# How to use postgres group by statement when joining tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a very simple query that i want to execute in postgres.
table1 has one to may relation to tables2 and 3.

pseudo query is as follows

```
select * from table1
  left join table2 ON table2.table1_id = table1.id
    left join table3 ON table3.table1_id = table1.id
group by table1.id
```

This gives me an error:
"column "table2.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function", 
same for table3.id

What is the point of Group by, if it forces me to add the id's of all the tables into group by, thus defeating the group by purpose( all ids are unique and no grouping occurs )

Comment: Well, your query does not make any sense in the first place. Group by is used to do some aggregation, while your query does none. You should explain what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: Counter question: What's the point of grouping, if you want the individual values rather than an aggregation?

Comment: The query is part of a search function, which searches fields from table2 and table3.
I dont care about all the entries that match in tables2 and 3, i just want 1 row for each id in table 1 that contains all the fields from table2 and table3

Comment: "i just want 1 row for each id in table 1 that contains all the fields from table2 and table3" all the fields of which row from `table2` and `table3`? You realize there can be more than one?

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of the `group by` is to summarize data.  There is one row in the result set for every combination of keys in the `group by`.

The columns in the result set are either keys in the `group by` or are aggregations.  There is one exception to this rule, involving grouping by unique or primary keys on a table and using other columns.

The use of `select *` with `group by` is simply not a correct use of aggregation in SQL.

You seem to be misunderstanding the purpose of this construct.  It is possible that you really mean `order by` -- that will order the result set by the the `order by` keys without changing (i.e. summarizing) the number of rows.